# How can I locate a zgemm error thrown by MKL?

Tags: fortran, intel-mkl

I have a big Fortran code and for some calculations I get this to stdout:

```
Intel MKL ERROR: Parameter 13 was incorrect on entry to ZGEMM
```

I tried to check the ldc-parameter for my most common zgemms, but I can't possibly check all of them by hand. Is there a way to trigger an error rather than just a warning, so I can find the location and possibly even get a core-dump?

Comment: I do not understand, you did get an error, not a warning. What exactly did you receive? What is the complete output? In your debugger you can make a condiitonal breakpoint in any location you want.  Be aware that MKL internals might  be assembly-only.  It may be well worth to swich to the reference LAPACK for debugging instead.

Comment: @VladimirF I think the OP is trying to distinguish between an error that aborts the code with optionally a core dump, and one that just stops without that useful information - he's calling the latter a "warning", which is not the best word ... But I agree, probably the simplest is to compile up the reference blas having changed the STOP in the error handler (xerbla.f) to something that forces a core dump, and link against that. That said it would be nice if MKL offered some kind of option to do this.

Comment: just a general remark: i think it is helpful to have some kind of matrix type which acts as a wrapper around blas, lapack. this way you dont have to call functions like `zgemm` by hand which is error prone. (e.g. `m, n, k, lda, ldb, ldc` could be computed on the fly by that matrix type.) the preprocessor helps in generic programming

Comment: @vladimirf This is the whole output. The program finishes normaly, but I get this line thousands of times to stdout.

Comment: I am basically asking if there are any environment variables that cause MKL to throw an error, rather than just write to the stdout.

Comment: Just try the reference LAPACK instead first.